# How to remove or change SourceTree hunk limit?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Apparently SourceTree only shows the first hunks in a modified file.

How do I get it to show **all** hunks?

Is there a setting to define the limit ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by the *Max Diff Line Count* setting on the *Diff* tab in the options window (the text caption may be truncated in some languages, e.g. it may show as `ener Zeilen` in German or `ne Count` in English).

The default value is 500.

Increase this value to a high enough number to ensure all your changes are shown.

Comment: Setting this value to `-1` seems to cause it to have no limit.

Or alternatively if you don't trust that, `2147483647` (the Java Integer upper limit) seems to be the largest acceptable value.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Tools -> Options -> Max Diff Line Count (Modify as per need)